# twitter bootstrap affix "refresh" method

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Twitter Bootstrap's Affix component lists a method called "refresh" which does not exist. I would imagine that this method would unbind (e.g. jQuery.off('affix.data.api') ) and the re-calculate the offsets (e.g. offset-top) given that a page may have been resized, DOM elements may have been added, removed, etc.

Since this method does not exist I'm curious if someone has found a work-around for "refreshing" all current affix elements on a page.

Comment: what do you mean by `refresh` doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
$('[data-spy=affix]').each(function () { $(this).data('affix').checkPosition(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are using either data spy or the javascript described method on http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix, and using the .affix('refresh') method and you have set the CSS to specify what happens to your divs when they are affixed?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is `$('#element').affix('checkPosition')` for bootstrap 3.1.x.